# Java-Junit/ misunderstanding of Junit method

Tags: java, junit

I have a method: `doctorQueue`, which get three paramets: Data type (by java.util.Date), Time and ID (string).

The return value is `void`, and if there is already queue in the same time, it gives an exeption.

I wrote the next method, using Junit:

```
public void checkQueueDoctor(){
Date date = new Date (2012,4,25);
Time time = new Time (13, 0, 0);
assertTrue(doctorQueue("83849829", date, time));
..... // and so on
}
```

It give me the next problem: `The method assertTrue(boolean) in the type Assert is not applicable for the arguments (void)`.

I of course understood it, but how I can check function, that it return value is void?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void checkQueueDoctor(){
  Date date = new Date (2012,4,25);
  Time time = new Time (13, 0, 0);
  doctorQueue("83849829", date, time);
   ..... // and so on
}
```

is sufficient.  If an exception is thrown the test will automatically fail.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test that an exception isn't thrown by a void method, a common pattern is:

```
try {
  doctorQueue("83849829", date, time);
  // if we make it to this line, success!
} catch (Exception e) {
  fail("queue adding threw an exception");
}
```

If you have another situation where you want to check that the method *does* throw an exception, just move the fail call to the other block:

```
try {
  doctorQueue(alreadyPresentElement, date, time);
  fail("expected an exception but didn't get one!");      
} catch (Exception e) {
  // we expected an exception and got it! Success!
}
```

(In either case it's probably better to catch a more specific exception than just `Exception`, by the way.)

Comment: If you want to test that an exception isn't thrown by a method, just call the method. By calling the method a try... catch, you are hiding the original exception

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JUnit 4, you can check for expected Exception, for example:

```
@Test(expected = Exception.class)
public void checkQueueDoctor() throws Exception {
   Date date = new Date (2012,4,25);
   Time time = new Time (13, 0, 0);
   doctorQueue("83849829", date, time);
}
```

You can look at this [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-junit4/index.html)

Comment: I think the question is how to test if an exception is not thrown.  I'm sure your example to test for an exception is useful for other scenarios the poster would want to test for though

Answer (score 0):

Check that the queue has changed after you added a doctor.

Answer (score 0):

> how I can check function, that it return value is void?

You can't. You can only check if it throws an exception when it should have thrown one e.g. bad arguments etc. and be informed via the `Assert.fail()`
What you could do is create a wrapper method that checks the side-effects of this method and return `true` or `false` and call that from the assert